# Javascript Resize Element Based on Browser Height

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to use Javascript/jQuery to resize part of a website based on the height of the window.

My code is as follows:

```
jQuery.event.add(window, "load", resizeFrame);
jQuery.event.add(window, "resize", resizeFrame);

function resizeFrame()
{
var h = $(window).height();
$(".main-wrapper").css('height', (h) ? h - 100);
}
```

What am I doing wrong? It doesn't seem to resize the section controlled by main-wrapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your conditional statement `(h) ? h - 100`. You have to provide a value for if `(h)` evaluates to false. The correct syntax is (cond ? exp<sub>true</sub> : exp<sub>false</sub>)

```
$(".main-wrapper").css('height', h ? h - 100 : default_value );
```